# Installing express in Terminal on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, express, operating-system

I get this code. I am on a Mac. I have installed npm. I am an Admin. What am I doing wrong? I've been googling for hours.

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro-3:Start Matt$ npm install express-generator -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└── express-generator@4.13.1 

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express-generator" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Matt/Start/Start/npm-debug.log
Matts-MacBook-Pro-3:Start Matt$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the npm cache and try the npm install again. You can use the following to clear the npm cache.

```
npm cache clean <path to express-generator>
```

Sometimes you get this error even when you are on ssh, the npm registry might be configured to use a different registry for npm packages and that registry might not have a express-generator

Comment: you can also try reinstalling npm if that doesn't work